# Uniquely identify host in db for a vcenter

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, hypervisor

I want to uniquely identify a host in database using combination of `vcenter` name and `uuid`. Since uuid can duplicated in different `vcenter`, how can I design a constraint for host table when it looks for combination `vcenter_name + host_uuid` to be unique.

```
__tablename__ = 'host'

# key values
# pylint: disable=invalid-name
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
hypervisor_type = Column(String, nullable=False)
uuid = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
name = Column(String)
ip = Column(String)
fqdn = Column(String)

vcenter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('vcenter.id', onupdate="CASCADE"))
vcenter = relationship('VcenterDBM', back_populates='hosts')

__table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('uuid', 'vcenter_id', name='uniq_hosts'),
)
```

Above constraint I have is not letting me add multiple hosts in same `vcenter` entry to db.

Comment: If the uuid can be a duplicate between different vcenters, then it is not universally unique, unless they are the same entity. And you should provide a [mcve]. What are you infact trying to put in the DB? The *uuid* column also has 2 unique constraints on it: it is unique by itself and it is part of the (uuid, vcenter_id) unique constraint. Finally, is it not the point of the unique constraint not to allow multiple hosts with the same uuid, vcenter_id?

Comment: I want to add hosts to db and I want to uniquely identify them using combination of uuid and vcenter_name.

Comment: You also have a single column unique constraint on uuid.